# How to recalculate the position of an object when adding using Instantiate? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, instantiation

I'm completely confused about the local and world coordinates of objects.
I have a hierarchy of objects like this:

[image]

I add LeftTargetPrefab with the previously saved position (for example Vector3(10f, 10f, 10f)) to BallsPath and it is set correctly. But if I try to add LeftTargetPrefab to BallTargets, then the position is also set to Vector3(10f, 10f, 10f). If, while starting the game, I create a clone of LeftTargetPrefab and drag it into BallsTarget, the coordinates are converted to local coordinates correctly. How can I make sure that when adding to BallsTarget via Instantiate, the LeftTargetPrefab(Clone) position is immediately correctly recalculated to the local one?

Answer (score 0):

Update after comments:

To instantiate the object relative to a new parent, use `Instantiate(originalObject, parentTransform, false`. This call uses the `instantiateInWorldSpace` boolean to set the Object's position relative to its new parent, see the below mentioned link.

Another thing: In your image, `LeftTargetPrefab` is a child of `BallsPath`. So it's coordinates are already not world coordinates anymore, but relative to its parent.

---

When you say "add LeftTargetPrefab with the previously saved position" does this happen from script during runtime?

You could try the `instantiateInWorldSpace` options of [Object.Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html). For this you would instantiate via the parent `Transform` (`BallsTarget` in this case, I guess).

Another option would be to pass the parent's position and a possible offset in terms of local coordinates via the `Transform.localPosition` etc of the parent object.

Comment: Yes, I save the position in PlayerPrefs and then load it on startup. 

How do I create an object specifying instantiateInWorldSpace if I create it like this:
target = Instantiate(_leftTargetPrefab, ballPattern.leftTargetPosition, Quaternion.identity);

I thought about calculating the offset, but in my game the angle and position of the object changes, so I'm looking into an easier way.

Comment: Maybe something like `target = Instantiate(_leftTargetPrefab, BallsTarget.Transform, false` will work. Note that you pass the parents Transform component, not the position itself.  Do you want to instantiate the prefab directly at the position of `BallsTarget`?

Comment: Yes, I need to create an object relative to BallsTarget

Comment: In your first comment, you mention `ballPattern.leftTargetPosition`. Where does this come from and where is it placed in the hierachry? Could you maybe show some of the code you use to instantiate the object?

Comment: **ballPattern.leftTargetPosition** is the value of the **BallPatern** class object in which the position is stored.
I add the object as I wrote in the comment above:
**target = Instantiate(_leftTargetPrefab, ballPattern.leftTargetPosition, Quaternion.identity);**

Comment: With a call like this, the position is passed as a world coordinate. Depending on whether you want the new Object to be a child of another object, I'd suggest to either pass the parent object directly, with the additional flags like specified above, or

Comment: solved with help **Vector3 position = _ballTargetsL.InverseTransformPoint(target.position);**